# DLL error while adding the environment into the jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, virtual-environment

I recently installed anaconda and created a new environment in a different location outside of anaconda base directory.
So I created the environment:

```
python -m venv tfod
```

Activated it

```
.\tensorflowenv\Scripts\activate
```

Upgraded pip and installed ipykernel

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
pip install ipykernel
```

Issue starts when i try to install/add this new environment into jupyter kernel so I can use this env

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=tensorflowenv
```

but getting this DLL error

```
File "D:\project\Tensorflow_obj\TFODCourse\tensorflowenv\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _device: The file cannot be accessed by the system.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't the exact "solution" for this but its a work around.

I created an environment using conda navigator and downloaded the required packages from navigator itself and then added the env into jupyter kernel using

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=tensorflowenv
```

**Still would be happy if someone can provide a actual solution for this**